# Web Part Storing Persistent Variable (ViewState/Session?)

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, viewstate

I am developing a custom SharePoint 2010 Web Part (not visual) in C#.

I need the ability to maintain persistent variables (selected value of a drop down list for example) across postbacks but have it be unique to each individual User and page/tab that the web part is in.  Storing the variable in Page.Session accomplishes the per user requirement but persists the variables value across the same windows/tabs for that user.  This [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54322/how-to-save-variables-per-user-session-per-page) describes what I have done, but it definitely not unique per window/tab.

I am not sure of the best way to store the variable, but I have attempted to use ViewState unsuccessfully.  I have confirmed in the web.config that it is enabled, but am unable to use ViewState in the same way I use Page.Session  Can anyone please help?

Perhaps Postback was not the correct term? My code is actually: Context.Response.Redirect(Context.Request.RawUrl);

Thanks,
MK

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are using "Context.Response.Redirect(Context.Request.RawUrl)"?

You are wiping out View-State data loading the page this way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 

I am essentially repainting the screen.  There is a SQL fed datagrid in the Web part.   A drop down list contains the list of tables in that SQL database.  I was trying to store a string that would maintain the selected value in the drop down list.  When the drop down list changes it redirects to the same page rebuilding the datagrid with the newly selected table. 

Right now I'm storing that string in Page . session, but that does not make each window/tab unique. 

Thanks, 
MK

Comment: Well, you could always load the new table in the datagrid in a Postback. You shouldn't need to load the entire page again. That being said, you should be able to use a QueryString to store your value.